# Popup window for close vote is showing wrong number for remaining vote count

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, voting-limits

Earlier, I was using flag for bringing inappropriate content to the attention of the community. Recently I got privilege to edit/close/reopen the question.

while doing my job I found the pop window for close question is **showing wrong count for remaining vote**.

It says I have 50 votes remaining for the day, while I have limit 40.
Can someone please clear me what is the reason for this?

Here is screen shot what I am getting while voting:

> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

50 votes remaining means 50 close votes remaining. 40 is your review limit. That means you can close question outside the review queue. (i.e. direct from the question).

Just for an example: Suppose you have reviewed 40 close votes for a day where you have casted 10 votes as *Leave Open* and 30 as close votes then your remaining close votes will be 20.
And there is nothing to do with badge or badge counter.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your time hims056, but I'm quite familiar with flag popup window and we have same badge count there **that shows 40 count for 40 limit**, so  I was confuse here.

Comment: @RDC you probably mean "inform moderator flags remaining" when you click the "flag" link. Those are different from close votes you have. And please stop using the word badge, which has a [different meaning](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges). The number in blue is a counter, showing how many (i.e. amount of) flags you still have.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, I'm sorry if the term badge is not good here, but we called badge for showing [notification-counts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722669/how-can-i-add-a-badge-to-a-standard-uibutton), which is same what we see here, btw thank you for your kind suggestion.